# How to access item in a list within dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I print last value (total) from dictionary.
From the example below the expected output is to print 90 for John and 110 for emma

```
mark_sht={'John': [40.0, 50.0, 90.0], 'emma': [50.0, 60.0, 110.0]}
St='Y'
while St.upper() != 'N':
    name=input("Enter name of student :")
    k=mark_sht.keys()
    if name in k: 
        print(mark_sht.values())
    St=input("Continue (Y/N):")
```

Comment: You click 'edit' and reformat your code with line breaks and indenting, then select it all and hit the `<>` button in the editor. This will format it in a readable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
mark_sht={'John': [40.0, 50.0, 90.0], 'emma': [50.0, 60.0, 110.0]}
St='Y'
while St.upper() != 'N':
    name=input("Enter name of student :")
    k=mark_sht.keys() 
    if name in k:
        print(mark_sht[name][-1])
    St=input("Continue (Y/N):")
```

---

**output:**

```
Enter name of student :John
90.0
Continue (Y/N):Y
Enter name of student :emma
110.0
Continue (Y/N):N
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while input('Enter Str').upper()=='Y':
    try:
        print(mark_sht[input('Enter Name')][-1])
    except:
        print('No such student')
```

The above code goes as follows:
The while loop intakes Str input by user directly.If the input is 'y'/'Y', we will enter the try section where if the Name enter by the user is a key in the dict 'mark_sht', the last score corresponding the name is printed. Else if the Name doesn't exists, it throws an error & goes in except section where we print 'no such student'

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.